# Raise after midyear review

Tags: raise

Is it appropriate to ask for a raise during a midyear performance assessment? I know from speaking with others that I am being underpaid significantly. I would like to address this with my boss in our review.

Comment: Mind telling us things like the industry and your location (state, country)?

Comment: How long have you been with the company? Is this your first performance review?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is absolutely appropriate to raise this during your review, especially if you expect a positive one. In fact this is what reviews are for. Don't wait for your boss to initiate this, it'll never happen.

For the rest of my answer, ie. how *exactly* to broach the subject, I refer you to answers in [this related question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1025/9549), except to add a few things:

1. You should've started the process six months ago by agreeing on goals for the next six months.
2. You should get an idea of your market value. This involves brushing up your resume and attending a few interviews. Doesn't mean you have to leave, but it's better to get in the war mentality and negotiate with your boss from a position of strength if you do land an offer.

Comment: Especially if the OP feels significantly underpaid, that means they feel they have a higher market value. Bringing this up in the performance review and while asking for a raise would be a lot more difficult for your boss to ignore. Especially if the performance review is highly positive.

Comment: Hi Rath. To provide you an update/get some feedback, I spoke with my boss about this and he was onboard with giving me a raise. I rationed with him how I was underpaid in the market and how people with much lower positions are making the same/more. He spoke with his boss (the CIO) and he in turn spoke with HR (whom I assume makes this final decision). It has been a month since this conversation, and when asked for an update, my boss told me "we're just waiting on HR". Is there a way I can expedite this, or perhaps do you suggest I follow up with her directly? Thanks

Comment: To further clarify, my boss is onboard with giving me a raise but doesn't have that authority. He has pleaded to the CIO that he really doesn't want to lose me. The raise is still in question.